# How to merge the child tags with other child tags in an xml using xslt 1.0 when the parent tag name is same?

Tags: xml, xslt, tags, xslt-1.0

This is my xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Nodes>
      <Designation Name="Minimum opening time">
        <Designation>Minimum opening time</Designation>
        <Car_No>8nn2</Car_No>
        <Sys>RSC</Sys>
        <Main>SDOR</Main>
        <Sub>SDOR</Sub>
        <Side>B1</Side>
        <Byte_N_x00B0>2</Byte_N_x00B0>
        <_x0030>X</_x0030>
        <_x0031>X</_x0031>
        <_x0032>X</_x0032>
        <_x0033>X</_x0033>
        <_x0034>X</_x0034>
        <_x0035>X</_x0035>
        <_x0036>X</_x0036>
        <_x0037>X</_x0037>
        <Car>2</Car>
        <Loc>1B</Loc>
        <Notes>unit time = 100 ms</Notes>
      </Designation>
      <Designation Name="DATE: Month number">
        <Designation>DATE: Month number</Designation>
        <Byte_N_x00B0>4</Byte_N_x00B0>
        <_x0030>apple</_x0030>
        <_x0031></_x0031>
        <_x0032></_x0032>
        <_x0033></_x0033>
        <_x0034></_x0034>
        <_x0035></_x0035>
        <_x0036>orange</_x0036>
        <_x0037>grapes</_x0037>
        <Notes>From 1 to 12 coded by 4 bits</Notes>
      </Designation>
      <Designation Name="DATE: Month number">
        <Designation>DATE: Month number</Designation>
        <Byte_N_x00B0>5</Byte_N_x00B0>
        <_x0030>pomegranate</_x0030>
        <_x0031>tomato</_x0031>
        <_x0032></_x0032>
        <_x0033></_x0033>
        <_x0034></_x0034>
        <_x0035></_x0035>
        <_x0036></_x0036>
        <_x0037></_x0037>
        <Notes>
        </Notes>
      </Designation>
    </Nodes>
```

I want to merge these type of parent tags(i.e) `Designation` into a single one if the `@Name` of the `Designation` is the same.

I need output something like this, to merge these two elements in xslt 1.0.
How can I achieve this using xslt 1.0, merging two parent elements?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Nodes>
      <Designation Name="Minimum opening time">
        <Designation>Minimum opening time</Designation>
        <Car_No>8nn2</Car_No>
        <Sys>RSC</Sys>
        <Main>SDOR</Main>
        <Sub>SDOR</Sub>
        <Side>B1</Side>
        <Byte_N_x00B0>2</Byte_N_x00B0>
        <_x0030>X</_x0030>
        <_x0031>X</_x0031>
        <_x0032>X</_x0032>
        <_x0033>X</_x0033>
        <_x0034>X</_x0034>
        <_x0035>X</_x0035>
        <_x0036>X</_x0036>
        <_x0037>X</_x0037>
        <Car>2</Car>
        <Loc>1B</Loc>
        <Notes>unit time = 100 ms</Notes>
      </Designation>
      <Designation Name="DATE: Month number">
        <Designation>DATE: Month number</Designation>
        <Byte_N_x00B0>4</Byte_N_x00B0>
        <Byte_N_x00B0>5</Byte_N_x00B0>
        <_x0030>apple</_x0030>
        <_x0030>pomegranate</_x0030>
        <_x0031>tomato</_x0031>
        <_x0032></_x0032>
        <_x0033></_x0033>
        <_x0034></_x0034>
        <_x0035></_x0035>
        <_x0036>orange</_x0036>
        <_x0037>grapes</_x0037>
        <Notes>From 1 to 12 coded by 4 bits</Notes>
        <Notes>
        </Notes>
      </Designation>
    </Nodes>
```

Comment: What do you mean by merge? Do you just want all of the descendants of `Designation`, or is there any special "merge" logic? You did not include `<Notes>From 1 to 12 coded by 4 bits</Notes>` in your example output. Was that just a mistake?

Comment: This seems to be a [grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info) question. Do a search - it's probably the most often asked XSLT question here. Grouping in XSLT 1.0 is best done using the Muenchian method: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: @MadsHansen Yes that is a mistake, and there is no logic as merge, I just want all the child tags of <Designation> if the Name attribute is same, i.e) DATE: Month number

Comment: Could you please edit your example and replace all those `X` values with recognizable (and different) values, so that we can understand what goes where?

Comment: Why are both _occurrences of `x0030` copied to the output but not both of `_x0032`?

Comment: Okay that is a mistake, just I want to add all the child tags if the parent tag name is same. Thats all. Even if the tags are empty also. @y.arazim

Comment: @Shalini Then you have a simple problem of grouping `Designation` by `@Name` and copying all child elements of each group. Once again: see http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html and the numerous examples of Muenchian grouping on SO.